# Linear fiber space of ideal sheaf and normal fiber space

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, coherent-sheaves

Suppose that $\left(M, \mathcal{O}\right)$ is an analytic space and $A$ is a subspace with defining coherent ideal sheaf $J$. One can construct from any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $M$ the linear fiber space $V\left(\mathcal{F}\right)$.

Moreover, there exist the tangent fiber spaces $TM$ and $TA$ and there is an embedding $\iota\colon TA \to TM\times_M A$. To me the generalization of the "normal vector bundle" would be the cokernel of $\iota$. However, Fischer defines the normal space of $A$ as the fiber space $V\left(J\right)$ associated to $J$.

My question is now: Is there an isomorphism $\text{coker}\left(\iota\right) \to V\left(J\right)\times_M A$?

I vaguely remember such a comment in the manifold case, but can not recall the source or the argument. I have not been able to come up with a proof, since I do not see a connection between the two fiber spaces.

Comment: Looks a lot like the adjunction formula, at least in the case of a local complete intersection.

Comment: Ah, of course, by construction $V\left(J\right)\times_M A = V\left(\iota^*J\right)$ and $\iota^*J= \iota^{-1}J / \iota^{-1}J^2$. That, paired with the assumption that the conormal sequence is short exact is the argument.